# How to compact folders in Thunderbird automatically?

Tags: thunderbird

I want to make sure folders are compacted regularly, but I don't ever want to see that prompt again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Compacting_folders#Automatically), you should be able to open up the `Config Editor…`, then set `mail.purge.ask` to `false`.